# How do I specifiy the param() section in a function so that I can call the function with either "F -opt val" or "F val_1 val_2"?

Tags: function, powershell, parameters

I am trying to write a PowerShell function that I can invoke using a switch and passing *one* value or not using the switch and passing *two* values:

```
option-or-value  -opt  one
option-or-value        two  three
```

I have assumed that I need parameter sets and need to define the `param()` section of the function as follows:

```
function option-or-value {
   param (

      [parameter (
          parameterSetName = 'using_option',
          mandatory        =  $true
       )][switch           ]                 $opt,

      [parameter (
          parameterSetName = 'using_value',
          mandatory        =  $true
       )][string           ]                 $val_0,

      [parameter (
          mandatory        =  $true
       )][string           ]                 $val_1
   ) 

   if ($using_option) {
       $val_0 = '...'
   }

   write-host "val_0 = $val_0, val_1 = $val_1"
}
```

However, I am doing something wrong and when I try to invoke the function, I get the error *A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument*.

This surprises me because I thought the entire point of parameter sets is that functions can differentiate between different parameter protocols.

So, where is my assumption wrong and how can I achieve such a function?

Comment: Is it important that it's a _switch_ parameter? It's probably easier to do with 3 string parameters across 2 parameter sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Mathias that it would be better to go with multiple Parameter Sets rather than using switches here.  He has the right answer but I think misinterpreted your question slightly which became more clear with your additional comment.

You would like to supply a switch and one value or not supply a switch and be forced to enter two values?  And you would like to have more than one switch which will determine what the function actually does.  To this point I don't agree as functions should typically be written to do one thing and do it well.  If you have multiple work that needs to be done then you should have different functions.

Anyways, I think instead of multiple switches I would recommend having only one parameter where you could specify the switch/action.  You could use `ValidateSet()` in order to restrict the input and provide autocompletion.  To the code!

```
function Test-OptionOrValue {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'Non-Option')]
    param (

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Options')]
        [ValidateSet( 'DoThis', 'DoThat', 'Other')]
        $Action,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Options')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Non-Option')]
        [string]
        $FirstValue,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Non-Option')]
        [string]
        $SecondValue
    )

    if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Non-Option') {
        Write-Host "Both FirstValue and SecondValue required"
        Write-Host "FirstValue: $FirstValue"
        Write-Host "SecondValue: $SecondValue"
    } elseif ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Options') {
        Write-Host "Action argument provided: $Action"
        Write-Host "Only FirstValue required"
        Write-Host "FirstValue: $FirstValue"
        Write-Host "SecondValue: $SecondValue"

        switch ($action) {
            'DoThis' { Write-Host "Performing 'DoThis' Action using FirstValue [$firstValue]" }
            'DoThat' { Write-Host "Performing 'DoThat' Action using FirstValue [$firstValue]" }
            'Other' { Write-Host "Performing 'Other' Action using FirstValue [$firstValue]" }
            Default {}
        }
    }
}
```

Usage Examples

```
PS > Test-OptionOrValue -Action DoThis -FirstValue 32

Action argument provided: DoThis
Only FirstValue required
FirstValue: 32
SecondValue:
Performing 'DoThis' Action using FirstValue [32]

PS > Test-OptionOrValue -Action DoThat -FirstValue 32

Action argument provided: DoThat
Only FirstValue required
FirstValue: 32
SecondValue:
Performing 'DoThat' Action using FirstValue [32]

PS > Test-OptionOrValue -FirstValue 12 -SecondValue 23

Both FirstValue and SecondValue required
FirstValue: 12
SecondValue: 23
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget about switches, make a third `[string]` parameter and declare it mandatory, as well as part of its own non-default parameter set instead:

```
function Test-Option
{
  [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'UsingValue')]
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'UsingValue', Position = 0)]
    [string]$FirstValue,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'UsingValue', Position = 1)]
    [string]$SecondValue = '...',

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'UsingOption')]
    [string]$Option
  )

  if($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'UsingOption'){
    $FirstValue = $Option
  }

  Write-Host "First: $FirstValue, Second: $SecondValue"
}
```

Giving you the desired behavior:

```
PS ~> Test-Option 123 456
First: 123, Second: 456
PS ~> Test-Option -Option 123
First: 123, Second: ...
PS ~> Test-Option -Option 123 456
Test-Optional : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '456'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Test-Option -Option 123 456
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Test-Option], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Test-Option
```

Comment: This does work (just to nitpick: the line reading `$FirstValue = $Option` should be `$SecondValue = $Option`). However, I am a bit reluctant to go this route as I there will be more possible options in the future (i.e. `Test-Option -doThis value`, `Test-Option -doThat value` etc) and the `-Option` (whichever it is) seems to be swalloed withouth `[switch]`.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by "swallowed"? Sounds like you want to inspect `$PSBoundParameters`?